# android ProgressBar without clipping?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Any default ProgressBar has a ClipDrawable level, for example a green Drawable is filling the grey background one on my device, the yellow on some others.

[image]

My question: is that possible to create a ProgressBar without this (partly) empty background when progress is less than max or should I use an ImageView instead? I need only the ClipDrawable to change its width so it looks like a diagram while the grey background never appears.

Comment: just change your gray background with transparent background : `android:color="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `layer-list` drawable like this.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#234"
                    android:centerColor="#234"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a24"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#144281"
                android:centerColor="#0b1f3c"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#06101d"
                android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

The main point is to make item with `android:id="@android:id/background` use `@android:color/transparent`

And then set it to `android:progressDrawable` property of `ProgressBar`

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/your_layer_list_created_on_previous_step"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="8dp" 
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminateOnly="false" 
    android:max="100" />
```

Comment: thanks. The background which is not filled stays transparent. How can I now add my own picture to use as progressDrawable?

Comment: didn't get the change.. I have my own stretchable drawable that I want to use as a ProgressBar while the background stays transparent. That's the thing I need

Comment: Then in `layer-list` item with `android:id="@android:id/progress` you have to remove `shape` and it content and update `clip` like this `<clip android:drawable="@drawable/your_stretchable_drawable">`. See docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip)